# Make all VBS files into one

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to compile all my many VBS files into one, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
Set sapi = CreateObject("SAPI.SPvoice")
Set wshShell  = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ChosenVBS = InputBox("Enter your message", "Choose What to run.")
Set WshShell  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Sub Speak
    Dim ProgramPath, WshShell, ProgramArgs, WaitOnReturn, intWindowStyle
    ProgramPath = "D:\Spam\Speak.vbs"
    ProgramArgs = ""
    intWindowStyle = 1
    WaitOnReturn = True
    WshShell.Run Chr(34) & ProgramPath & Chr(34) & Space(1) & ProgramArgs, _
        intWindowStyle, WaitOnReturn
End Sub

Call ChosenVBS
```

How I'm trying to do it currently, the `Set` are for all the codes I'm going to put in.

Comment: Please share your VBS files. What is the exact issue?

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What are you trying to accomplish by merging multiple VBScript files into one?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am trying to make a access file for all the files, instead of just searching through all the folders, I could just type the program I want and it will open there.

Comment: That is impractical. Better put all your scripts in one directory and add that directory to your PATH environment variable. Then you can simply run the scripts from the Run dialog or a CMD or PowerShell prompt.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't really care if it is impractical for VBS/Other scripts, If it works for VBS files, it can work for other things too, which can be useful to me.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Don't do what you're trying to do. Do what I told you to do. Clearer now?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Still not clear, why not?
Is it a big problem to try?

Comment: It's not a problem, just a waste of time and effort. The suggested approach works out-of-the-box and also on different operating systems.

Comment: Eh, i'd rather make a VBS that does it than add it to PATH.
So, does anyone know a fix to my problem?

Can I set a variable as a variable?